# Is there a performance difference when using blocks to control scope within a switch statement?

Tags: c#, performance

I can't find a standard anywhere about this, but something about it seems fishy. I want to know is there objectively a performance difference using code blocks to control scope from within a switch statement.

Here is an example.

If I do this, I get an error.

```
        SomeEnum response = GetResponse();

        switch (response)
        {
            case SomeEnum.foo:
                    string result = HandleFoo();
                    HandleResult(result);
                break;

            case SomeEnum.bar:
                    string result = HandleBar();
                    HandleResult(result);
                break;

            case SomeEnum.baz:
                    string result = HandleBaz();
                    HandleResult(result);
                break;
        }
```

[image]

So there are two alternatives:

#### Alternative #1 I create three different variable names.

```
        SomeEnum response = GetResponse();

        switch (response)
        {
            case SomeEnum.foo:
                string fooResult = HandleFoo();
                HandleResult(fooResult);
                break;

            case SomeEnum.bar:
                string barResult = HandleBar();
                HandleResult(barResult);
                break;

            case SomeEnum.baz:
                string bazResult = HandleBaz();
                HandleResult(bazResult);
                break;
        }
```

Although this solved the issue, it's messy and can get hard to follow, plus if I copy and paste (since they all look so similar) I could accidentally do something like this.

```
...
            case SomeEnum.foo:
                    string barResult = HandleBar();
                    HandleResult(barResult);
                break;
...
```

And I'll have a serious logic error.

#### Alternative #2 I use code blocks to control scope within the switch statement.

```
        SomeEnum response = GetResponse();

        switch (response)
        {
            case SomeEnum.foo:
                {
                    string result = HandleFoo();
                    HandleResult(result);
                }
                break;

            case SomeEnum.bar:
                {
                    string result = HandleBar();
                    HandleResult(result);
                }
                break;

            case SomeEnum.baz:
                {
                    string result = HandleBaz();
                    HandleResult(result);
                }
                break;
        }
```

So ignoring the obvious solution here. (defining the string outside of the switch statement and calling `HandleResult()` at the end. I haven't seen anyone do this  but it reads a lot cleaner.

I know very little about how C# is working in the background but it seems like it would be better to use the blocks because we don't need to dedicate space for three strings from the heap, but only for one.

But I guess my biggest question is, is there any performance gained by using one over the other?

Comment: Why do you need a variable at all? Why not just use `handleResult(handleFoo());`?

Comment: I have removed the question about "is this bad practice" and avoid phrasing like "is it better" - unless you've objectively defined the criteria for "better", the answer is otherwise opinionated.  Your question about "is there performance gained" is valid though.

Comment: Declaring them all separatey means you have three separate variables compiled into the function. But the Jitter (at least in Release build) will usually inline them into using the same location. So there should be no perf difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need code blocks, you can define the string variable once before the switch and use it in all branches.
Assuming your switch statements covers all the options, you can also call the `HandleResult` method just once, after the switch:

```cs
SomeEnum response = GetResponse();
string result;
switch (response)
{
    case SomeEnum.foo:
        result = HandleFoo();
        break;

    case SomeEnum.bar:
        result = HandleBar();
        break;

    case SomeEnum.baz:
        result = HandleBaz();
        break;
    // either add that or set a default value to the result variable, 
    // otherwise you'll get a compilation error:
    // CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'result'
    default:
        return;
}
HandleResult(result);
```

If you choose to use switch this way, and using c# 8 or later, you might as well use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), which will make you code much more concice and (IMHO) readable:

```
SomeEnum response = GetResponse();
var result = response switch  
{  
     SomeEnum.foo => HandleFoo(),  
     SomeEnum.bar => HandleBar(),  
     SomeEnum.baz => HandleBaz(),  
    _ => null, // or any default value you choose  
};
```

I don't think there's a performance penalty for any of options, and even if there is one, it's probably so small that you won't notice it unless running in a very tight loop - but that can be tested using benchmarks.

In any case - now a days, readability and maintainability are much more important than performance in almost all cases, so unless you're writing something that's going to be very performance-critical you should prefer maintainability over performance.